# How to share my app in facebook directly in android?

Tags: android, facebook

From my app, i am sharing the details in the facebook. But when i am clicking in the share button, it is first showing a drop-down list with facebook, gmail, tweeter etc. If i choose the facebook, then it is taking me to facebook and able to share there.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://market.android.com/details?id=com.healthtap.userhtexpress&feature=featured-apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDIwMywiY29tLmhlYWx0aHRhcC51c2VyaHRleHByZXNzIl0.");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```

But, i do not want that drop-down. I want to go directly to the facebook page when i will click to the facebook share button. How it is possible??

Answer (score 1):

This post may be help.

http://thetechnib.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-facebook-integration.html

Comment: But here i have to use facebook SDK. I want to do it using Intent only. Is there any way?

Comment: An intent can be used with startActivity to launch an Activity, broadcastIntent to send it to any interested BroadcastReceiver components.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps the choosing between Intent and Facebook SDK is the situation. An intent can be used with startActivity to launch an Activity, broadcastIntent to send it to any interested BroadcastReceiver components. Who the data is being delivered to is not specified. So, there is no option to specify the explicit activity name. But,there is a possibility, if u know the exact name of the activity of the Facebook App, u could directly call it in your own code. If not, use Facebook SDK is the option.